# Floating dunst notification in i3

Tags: linux, notifications, i3

### My problem

I'm under Ubuntu 22.04 with [i3](https://github.com/i3/i3) as windows manager and [dunst](https://github.com/dunst-project/dunst) to display the notifications.

I would like the notifications to be floating but they are at the top of the screen and take the whole width.

You will find bellow parts of my config for dunst and i3, and the output of `xprop` on a notification.

`xprop` shows that the notification is a window with class `"Dunst"` but i3 doesn't show it as a floating window even if it is configured to do so with windows for which the class is `"Dunst"`. How can I fix this?

### My config files

`~/.config/dunst/dunstrc`:

```ini
[global]
width = 300
height = 300
origin = top-right
offset = 10x50
scale = 0
title = Dunst
class = Dunst
```

`~/.config/i3/config`:

```bash
for_window [window_role="pop-up"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="task_dialog"] floating enable
for_window [class="Dunst"] floating enable
```

### Additional information

`xprop` command on a notification gives me:

```bash
_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY(CARDINAL) = 3650722120
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_UTILITY
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Dunst", "Dunst"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Dunst"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Dunst"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/wndrkw/is_i3_making_dunst_notifications_full_width/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

I changed my `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc` with (use `geometry`):

```ini
[global]
geometry = "300x5-10+50"
title = Dunst
class = Dunst
```

Comment: You've found that Ubuntu 22.04 ships with dunst 1.5.0 and that the "geometry" directives you were using require a later version. Current version is 1.9.0 and it's easily installed from source if you're interested.